# How can I undo wrong permissions in my git working copy? Should I just clone again?

Tags: git, git-clone

I just cloned a directory. While setting up my local files I accidentally set the wrong permissions to a directory and everything inside that folder (chmod -R 777 /foo).

What I would like to do is 'start from scratch'. Is this as simple as deleting my files inside my dev folder and then running the clone command again?

Answer (score 5):

This will restore the files in the working copy to the permissions in the HEAD commit.

```
git ls-tree -r HEAD|while read mode _ _ fpath; do chmod "$mode" "$fpath"; done
```

Comment: Great answer! Worked perfect for me.

Comment: this returns.. chmod: invalid mode: ‘100644’

Comment: I fixed with this... but would like to understand... `git ls-tree -r  d3fb093 |while read mode _ _ fpath; do chmod "${mode:3}" "$fpath"; done`

Comment: excellent solution. used on my Mac to fix permission changes while migrating files from another computer. keeps all other unstaged changes intact too!

Comment: I faced invalid mode 100644 on my ubuntu 22.04 too

Answer (score 4):

You can also just revert all of the changes to the work tree with `git reset --hard`.

Comment: but this will revert not only permissions but also file content.

Answer (score 4):

You can do that, or you can revert. I would suggest you get in the habit of reverting, because **that is what git is for!**

The point is, you mess up and git will get you back to a previous checkin. It isn't just a place to shove your code, but a lifesaver for when Things Go Horribly Wrong. Perhaps you made a change and now something is broken. What do you do? Use Git to figure out what changed or just revert back to the latest working version!

If you're going to blow away the files in your dev folder, make sure you blow away the `.git` directory, too.